# How do I change a text label in ViewController from AppDelegate in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'd like to change the text of text label in ViewController when App will enter foreground. Please let me know how to use the ViewController's objects from AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a message via NotificationCenter and respond to the method in the view controller. This is how I do it since ever and it's not dependent of the language.